# variable scope in woocommerce filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My page need to display a different product name in the woocommerce email for the admin (new customer order email). To change the name i use the filter **woocommerce_order_item_name**.
But i must verify if it is an admin email or customer email. I use a gloab variable in this code and it works but it's not the proper way i guess. So is there a better solution to verify it's an admin email or customer email?

**woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php**

```
global $is_admin_email;
if($show_sku) {
    $is_admin_email = True;
}
else {
    $is_admin_email = False;

// Product name
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item, false );
//Set to false again
$is_admin_email = False;
```

**functions.php**

```
function filter_woocommerce_order_item_name( $item_name, $item, $false ) { 
    global $is_admin_email;
    if( $is_admin_email ){
        $item_name = "Item name in admin email";
    }

    return $item_name; 
};

// add the filter
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find a hook that shows up in the emails and includes the variable `$sent_to_admin` which is `true` when sent to an admin. This sounds like it would serve as the perfect conditional for your needs.

So, I would try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'so_43094965_order_item_names', 10, 4 ); 

function so_43094965_order_item_names( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    if( $sent_to_admin ){
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 3 );
    }
}
```

This adds your filter, but only if your in an admin email.

And then:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'so_43094965_remove_order_item_names', 10, 4 ); 

function so_43094965_remove_order_item_names( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 3 );
}
```

This removes it so it doesn't appear in other places... I'm not sure if it is needed, but for completeness I'm throwing it out there.

This is untested, so your mileage may vary.